# How much does it cost to sponsor a tag?

Tags: support, advertising, sponsored-tags

With almost 30,000 tags, it would be nice to be able to sponsor very low traffic tags.  The low volume tags are actually quite interesting.  For example, if you have a business repairing **altair** computers, it would be great to be able to sponsor the one question tagged [altair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/altair).

Comment: +1 just for bringing to my attention the "altair" tag, lol

Comment: altair tag has been burnified apparently :|

Comment: The tag is back, but it now means something entirely different.

Comment: As sponsoring tags is a Stack Overflow-only feature, voting to close this as only applicable to one site.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog, since it is possible to [sponsor a whole site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322338/282094) I would not suggest that tag sponsorship is limited to a single site.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[image]

> To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at ads@stackexchange.com [...].

Comment: Tongue not in cheek - I bet the official answer would be a riff on, "It depends." with a request for more information on the tag you want to sponsor.

Comment: +1 for freehand circles *and* the correct answer. Tag sponsorship is avaiable to advertisers who buy most of the ads for a tag. So yes, "it depends" widely on the tag, etc.