# Tags with icons?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

[image]

Please check the tags of "Android" which is a tag with a icon only i think. I am interested to know below things:

- Who creates tags with icon (I know user having 1500 reputation can create tags)
  Or 
  who provides icon to this tag, moderator or any else?
- Who has created this android tag with icon?
- What if i want to provide icon for the existing tag, say for example iPhone, blackberry? What the steps i need to?

Comment: @Pubby i think my question is how do we create tag with icon? Because there is no way we can provide icon while creating tag.

Comment: If you want to provide icon for an existing tag then you would have to sponsor it. More info here: [How much does it cost to sponsor a tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30988/how-much-does-it-cost-to-sponsor-a-tag). "To buy ads or inquire about tag sponsorships, please contact us at ads@stackexchange.com, call +1-212-232-8280".

Comment: @balpha still i am confused for "Who creates tag with icon"? You have closed this question as a duplicate but i didn't found any information as such.

Comment: Did you even read Aziz' comment?