# Why doesnt the iOS tag has an Icon just like the Android one?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)

I was wondering why doesnt the iOS tag has an icon, the android one has one, windows phone also has one, but not the iOS. It is true that the icon is actually the word iOS but im pretty sure it would be easier to stop if it actually had the real icon:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Apple_iOS.svg

I know you can just filter by tag to see questions with ios tag but i feel its a bit lame that the others have and the ios doesnt.

Comment: That's not even an icon.

Comment: well its a logo which can be used as the icon right?

Comment: What the hell is up with Apple and gradient fills on text?  Did they *just* download Photoshop for the first time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tags that have icons are those that have been sponsored.

Apple (or anyone else) has not sponsored the iOS tag.

See [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30187/140505).

Comment: So in order to get one we actually have to ask apple to sponsor it?

Comment: @LuisOscar - Apple or _anyone else_. For a tag to be sponsored, I believe money needs to exchange hands. Not sure it matters whose money...

Answer (score 4):

It's a [sponsored tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean).

Android has paid SO to put the icon there, [as well as some links on the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-sdk+android). iOS hasn't. For that matter, IIRC *anyone* can sponsor a tag. If you have the moolah, feel free to do it for iOS ;-)

See also:

[Adobe-sponsored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23955/adobe-sponsored-tags)

[How much does it cost to sponsor a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30988/how-much-does-it-cost-to-sponsor-a-tag)

[Should tags that represent concepts be sponsorable?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33081/should-tags-that-represent-concepts-be-sponsorable)