# How does one add an icon to a tag?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do icons on the tags mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30187/what-do-icons-on-the-tags-mean)
>   [How much does it cost to sponsor a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30988/how-much-does-it-cost-to-sponsor-a-tag)

I see, for example, that the google-chrome tag has an icon, but firefox doesn't.

How is it possible to add an icon to the firefox tag?

Comment: To summarise you would have to pay (I suspect a lot) to sponsor the tag - it's designed for companies to get some extra marketing by standing out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [these guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104757/131713), you would basically have to

1. be Mozilla, and
2. be willing to shell out a non-trivial amount of money

If you only want to do it for your own machine, you could look at the markup for [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) and write a userscript to replicate it for [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) with an icon you supply.